# Cannot figure out why I'm getting the following error: "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to the trim the blanks from all cells of a column using the following Sub but when I go to write the contents of the array back to my spreadsheet I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my sub:

```
Sub TrimIDCUST()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
          Set wks = ShCust            'Work in sheet("shCust")
          Dim LastRow As Long
            ' Find last row shCust
            LastRow = ShCust.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
            
     Dim i As Long
     Dim CustID() As Variant
          CustID = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value)
     
     For i = LBound(CustID) To UBound(CustID)
          CustID(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(CustID(i))
     Next i
     wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(CustID)
End Sub
```

I have used this basic framework successfully before and am stumped.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If it matters Im using Office 365 on a Mac.

Comment: Why use `Transpose` at all?  How many rows are in your range? (Transpose starts to do funny things with arrays gt about 64,000

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array or a loop to do this. Use the late-bound `Application.Trim` (`Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim` is early-bound).

```
With wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
   .Value = Application.Trim(.Value)
End With
```

---

As mentioned in comments, you don't need `Transpose` and it can cause issues. If you're going the long way, simply work with the 2D `Variant` array and skip transposing.

```
CustID = wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value

For i = LBound(CustID, 1) To UBound(CustID, 1)
    CustID(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(CustID(i, 1))
Next i

wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = CustID
```

Comment: BigBen, I tried both suggestions (with and without an array) and recieved the same error both times. I'm clearly missing something basic.
Cant figure out how to post a response with code, here is my best attempt.
```Sub TrimIDCUST()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ShCust            'Work in sheet("shCust")

    Dim LastRow As Long
      ' Find last row shCust
    LastRow = ShCust.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
    With wks.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        .Value = Application.Trim(.Value)
    End With
End Sub```

Comment: I'm guessing an element in your array begins with `=` after you `Trim`? There's some element of your array that Excel doesn't like writing to the sheet. Could debug further by attempting to write the elements of the array in a loop.

Comment: No "=" in data only captial letters and numbers

Comment: I'd still try writing the elements one-by-one to see which is the culprit. Does the sheet have any protection applied?

Comment: That, or try changing the cell format to Text: add `.NumberFormat = "@"` after the `With` statement.

Comment: BigBen - This is getting weird. I can now get the sub TrimIDCUST to run once but if I try to rerun it on the "Trimmed" data I get the "Method 'Value' of object "Range' failed" error. Does that make any sense??

Comment: Not without sample data to reproduce unfortunately.

Comment: How can I provide you with some sample data? I've never supplied sample data on this forum before.

Comment: A link to a Google Sheet or a file hosted in OneDrive for example.